# angular 9 array is empty inside subscription method

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I have an array which is declared as public and initialized as a empty array.

```
correctives = [];
```

Now Inside constructor method I initialized the subscription method

```
constructor(private messageService: MessageService){
    this.childTicketSubscribe = this.messageService.getChildTicketData().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.correctives)); //[]
        // print empty array
    });
}
```

Now I'm initializing it inside OnInit method

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.correctives = [{value: ''}];
}
```

Now I have two method:
1 to add data into the array

```
addCorrective() {
    this.correctives.push({value: ''});
}
```

Another one to call another component and the data from another component is coming inside the subscription method.

So when I add three data into the array and then click the other function to get the data from other component.After getting the data inside the subscription method,I print the `this.correctives` and it is blank. But it should be three values as I added them previously.
What is the error in This code?

**Edited**: Also I found ,Inside the subscription method ,If I push any thing Inside an array,Every time It only stores the lates value,Not the all previous one.Is this the original behaviuor?

Comment: It is impossible to tell what is going on with the code you have provided. Create a StackBlitz that recreates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add your subscription code in **ngAfterViewInit** method.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.childTicketSubscribe = this.messageService.getChildTicketData().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.correctives)); //[]
        // print empty array
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the array in both Constructor and OnInit, pressumely OnInit should modify the array after Constructor, But subscribe could happen after OnInit.

Comment: I also modified it inside a function named 'addCorrective'.Everything is working fine but inside subscription method it is blank

Comment: Because the constructor method will be executed before the ngOninit method that's why it will be blank, just try to the initialization inside the component when declaring your array!

Comment: easiest solution here is to move your subscribe code to OnInit